# How to remove skype extras from Skype?

Tags: windows, skype, bloatware

How to remove "skype extras" from Skype 4.1 for Windows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you do not need to uninstall Skype. Just run the installer and uncheck "Skype Extras Manager".

See this article :  [skype extras manager - an amazing resource hog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/spywaresucks/archive/2007/06/04/941269.aspx)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for not re-installing Skype is to disable the Skype Extras Manager service from 
services.msc utility.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no direct uninstall for it. You have to uninstall it entirely, then when you reinstall, uncheck the "Install Extras Manager" checkbox.